# WCF services not working on the server

Tags: asp.net, wcf

WCF service is not working on the server. I am getting following error

> The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
>   For more information about the error, either turn on
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute
>   or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in
>   order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on
>   tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and
>   inspect the server trace logs.

It is working for me in localhost

I have also set endpoint address in web.config

```
   <service name="Myproject.project.Web.UI.SurveyServices">
      <endpoint adress="http://www.abc.com/SurveyServices/SurveyServiceWeb.svc" 
      behaviorConfiguration="Myproject.project.Web.UI.SurveyServices.SurveyServiceWebAspNetAjaxBehavior" 
      binding="webHttpBinding" 
      contract="Myproject.project.Web.UI.SurveyServices.SurveyServiceWeb" />
   </service>
```

I am using using Microsoft.Practices.Unity for data access. While looking at the exception detail following error was returned.

```
 Some internal error occured while processing your request please try again later Error:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

       at MyProject.Project.Web.Extensions.UnityUtiliy.GetContainer() in E:\HostingSpaces\montotec\myproject.domain.com\wwwroot\MyProject.Project.Web.Extensions\UnityUtiliy.cs:line 62

       at MyProject.Project.Business.Surveys.SurveyServiceManager.GetSurveyDetailsBySurveyId(Int32 SurveyId) in E:\HostingSpaces\montotec\Myproject.domain.com\wwwroot\Myproject.project.Business.Surveys\SurveyServiceManager.cs:line 31"
```

Comment: *"For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.0 SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs."* - Have you followed this advice yet?  What additional details about the error have you found?

Comment: There are many probable causes. From server configurations to publishing problems, from acces right and hardcoded stuff that will only work on your computer and so on. Follow the guidelines in the message error to find out what is actually going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for reply! IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults is already turn on on the server

Comment: If the exception detail is already being included, then what are the details of the exception?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Practices.Unity; to access the data and I was getting following error

Comment: Some internal error occured while processing your request please try again later Error:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

   at Myproject.project.Web.Extensions.UnityUtiliy.GetContainer() in E:\HostingSpaces\montotec\www.xyz.com\wwwroot\Myproject.project.Web.Extensions\UnityUtiliy.cs:line 62

   at Myproject.project.Business.Surveys.SurveyServiceManager.GetSurveyDetailsBySurveyId(Int32 SurveyId) in E:\HostingSpaces\montotec\www.xyz.com\wwwroot\Myproject.project.Business.Surveys\SurveyServiceManager.cs:line 31

Comment: Can you post code from your UnityUtiliy.cs? Hard to tell from this, but  have you set up your registrations correctly (Interfaces to Implementations)?

Comment: IUnityContainer container = HttpContext.Current.Application[containerKey] as IUnityContainer; I was getting System.NullReferenceException error from above line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved solved this issues

to resolved this issue I was set `<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">`
under `<system.serviceModel>`